# A non-orientable vector bundle (rank $n$), for any collection of sections {$s_1, …,s_n$}, at least one subset of $E_b$ is zero? $s_i(b)=0$

Tags: vector-bundles

Solved questions (see the comment below):

- For a vector bundle $E\rightarrow B$, if there are $n$ linearly independent sections {$s_1,…,s_n$} (i.e. trivial bundle). We take a linearly independent subset of $E_b$ for $b\in B$: {$s_1(b),…,s_n(b)$}.
  Does it mean for any $b\in B$, $s_1(b)\ne0$, $s_2(b)\ne0$,..., $s_n(b)\ne0$? >>>> True.
- For a vector bundle cannot admit $n$ linearly independent sections (i.e. non-trivial bundle), if I still select a collection of sections {$s_1, …,s_n$}, does it mean there is at least one subset of $E_b$ is zero, i.e. $s_i(b)=0$? >>> Not True.

Updated question:

- A non-orientable rank $n$ vector bundle $E\rightarrow B$, for any collection of sections {$s_1, …,s_n$}, there is at least one subset of $E_b$ is zero, i.e. $s_i(b)=0$, $b\in B$?

Comment: This boils down to linear algebra. If $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ is a linearly independent subset of a vector space, can we have $v_i = 0$ for some $i$? If $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ is not linearly independent, must we have $v_i = 0$ for some $i$?

Comment: @MiChaelAblanese, thanks for the comment. Indeed, I was confused about whether it is the same as the linear algebra. So the conclusion is:  If the set is a linearly independent, we cannot have $v_i=0$ .  If the set is not linearly independent, it is not true that  $v_i=0$ for some $i$. Is it correct?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Inspired by your comment, I updated the question: If the vector bundle is non-orientable, there must exists $s_i(b)=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\gamma\oplus\varepsilon^1 \to S^1$ where $\gamma$ and $\varepsilon^1$ denote the non-trivial and trivial line bundles over $S^1$ respectively. Note that $w_1(\gamma\oplus\varepsilon^1) = w_1(\gamma) \neq 0$, so the bundle is non-orientable. As $\varepsilon^1$ is trivial, it admits a nowhere-zero section $s$. Now set $s_k = (0, ks)$ and note that for $k \neq 0$, the section $s_k$ is a nowhere-zero section of $\gamma\oplus\varepsilon^1$. In particular, $\{s_1, s_2\}$ is a collection of nowhere-zero sections of $\gamma\oplus\varepsilon^1$. That is, the answer to your question is no.